# I would like to make a loop with this code to have several card swith a object

Tags: javascript, json

`enter code here`hello I would like to loop on a json file to create maps but I can't find the loop I need, here is my obect json

```
type here javascript
let element=document.createElement`
<div class="grid-item-product">
    <img src="${Produits.img}" alt="${Produits.id}">
   <div class="card-content">
        <button id="control-price-sucette">
            <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-pen"></i>
       </button>
       <h3>${title}</h3> 
        <span>A partir de <strong id="price-sucette">${price} €</strong> </span>
</div>
    </div>
 `
 product.appendChild(element)
```

```
enter code hereexport const Produits= [ 
{
    id:"sucette",
    img:"./images/sucette.jpg",
    title:"Sucette",
    Price:25,
    reduction:0,
    
},
{
    id :"cannes",
    img:"./images/canne.jpg",
    title : "Cannes",
    price : 25,
    reduction:30
},
{
    id:"oursons",
    title:"Ourson",
    img:"./image/ourson",
    price:20,
    reduction:0
},
{
    id:"bonbon_durs",
    title:"Bonbons durs",
    img:"./images/dur.jpg",
    price: 39,
    reduction:25
},
{
    id:"bonbon_acidulées",
    title:"Bonbons acidulées",
    img:"./image/acidul.jpg",
    price:30,
    reduction:0
},
{
    id:"brochette",
    title:"Brochette",
    img:"./images/brochette.jpg",
    price:30,
    reduction:20 
},
{
    _id: "cake_balls",
    get id() {
        return this._id
    },
    set id(value) {
        this._id = value
    },
    img:"./images/cake-ball.jpg",
    title:"Cake bals",
    price:40,
    reduction:20
},
{
    _id_1: "cake_pops",
    get id() {
        return this._id_1
    },
    set id(value) {
        this._id_1 = value
    },
    title:"cake pops",
    img:"./images/cake-pops.jpg",
    price:50,
    reduction:30
},
{
    id: "cake_pops_coeur",
    title:"cake pops coeur",
    img:"./images/cake-pops-coeur",
    price:50,
    reduction:20
}
```

]

Comment: What you mean "I can't find the loop I need"?. Can you please elaborate more on the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the loop at that JSON using `.forEach` method. Try this:

```js
const Produits= [ 
{
    id:"sucette",
    img:"./images/sucette.jpg",
    title:"Sucette",
    Price:25,
    reduction:0,
    
},
{
    id :"cannes",
    img:"./images/canne.jpg",
    title : "Cannes",
    price : 25,
    reduction:30
},
{
    id:"oursons",
    title:"Ourson",
    img:"./image/ourson",
    price:20,
    reduction:0
},
{
    id:"bonbon_durs",
    title:"Bonbons durs",
    img:"./images/dur.jpg",
    price: 39,
    reduction:25
},
{
    id:"bonbon_acidulées",
    title:"Bonbons acidulées",
    img:"./image/acidul.jpg",
    price:30,
    reduction:0
},
{
    id:"brochette",
    title:"Brochette",
    img:"./images/brochette.jpg",
    price:30,
    reduction:20 
},
{
    _id: "cake_balls",
    get id() {
        return this._id
    },
    set id(value) {
        this._id = value
    },
    img:"./images/cake-ball.jpg",
    title:"Cake bals",
    price:40,
    reduction:20
},
{
    _id_1: "cake_pops",
    get id() {
        return this._id_1
    },
    set id(value) {
        this._id_1 = value
    },
    title:"cake pops",
    img:"./images/cake-pops.jpg",
    price:50,
    reduction:30
},
{
    id: "cake_pops_coeur",
    title:"cake pops coeur",
    img:"./images/cake-pops-coeur",
    price:50,
    reduction:20
}];

let elements = '';
Produits.forEach((p)=>{
  elements += `
    <div class="grid-item-product">
      <img src="${p.img}" alt="${p.id}">
      <div class="card-content">
        <button id="control-price-sucette">
          <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-pen"></i>
        </button>
        <h3>${p.title}</h3> 
        <span>A partir de <strong id="price-sucette">${p.price} €</strong> </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;
});
let product = document.getElementById("product");
product.innerHTML = elements;
```

```css
.grid-item-product {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/js/all.min.js"></script>

<div id="product"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear from your question what you need.
Although i think you want to loop over the Items to get their attributes.
In this case i think this should work:

```
myArray.map((item, index) => {
        console.log(item.id, item.title, item.price);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

#### The best loop is Javascript's `.map` function.

Your HTML will need:

- an opening DIV
- a loop, producing the repeating rows (one for each product)
- a closing DIV

The `.map` function maps the array of products to an array of strings (not to a single long string) so you can use the `.join` function to join the individual strings into one long one.

Et voilà:

```js
const Produits = [{
    id: "sucette",
    img: "./images/sucette.jpg",
    title: "Sucette",
    Price: 25,
    reduction: 0,

  },
  {
    id: "cannes",
    img: "./images/canne.jpg",
    title: "Cannes",
    price: 25,
    reduction: 30
  },
  {
    id: "oursons",
    title: "Ourson",
    img: "./image/ourson",
    price: 20,
    reduction: 0
  },
  {
    id: "bonbon_durs",
    title: "Bonbons durs",
    img: "./images/dur.jpg",
    price: 39,
    reduction: 25
  },
  {
    id: "bonbon_acidulées",
    title: "Bonbons acidulées",
    img: "./image/acidul.jpg",
    price: 30,
    reduction: 0
  },
  {
    id: "brochette",
    title: "Brochette",
    img: "./images/brochette.jpg",
    price: 30,
    reduction: 20
  },
  {
    _id: "cake_balls",
    get id() {
      return this._id
    },
    set id(value) {
      this._id = value
    },
    img: "./images/cake-ball.jpg",
    title: "Cake bals",
    price: 40,
    reduction: 20
  },
  {
    _id_1: "cake_pops",
    get id() {
      return this._id_1
    },
    set id(value) {
      this._id_1 = value
    },
    title: "cake pops",
    img: "./images/cake-pops.jpg",
    price: 50,
    reduction: 30
  },
  {
    id: "cake_pops_coeur",
    title: "cake pops coeur",
    img: "./images/cake-pops-coeur",
    price: 50,
    reduction: 20
  }
]

const html =  "<div>" + 
Produits.map(produit => `
<div class="grid-item-product">
    <img src="${produit.img}" alt="${produit.id}">
    <div class="card-content">
        <button id="control-price-sucette">
            <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-pen"></i>
       </button>
       <h3>${produit.title}</h3> 
           <span>A partir de <strong id="price-sucette">${produit.price} €</strong> </span>
    </div>    
</div>
`).join("") 
+ "</div>"

const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = html;

document.querySelector('body').appendChild(div)
```